# How to extract histograms from a root file and print them but writing them in a macro to run

Tags: root-framework

So when I extract a histogram from my root file I do it the following way

```
root -l output_idAntiId_Mc16a.root
root [0]
Attaching file output_idAntiId_Mc16a.root as _file0…
(TFile ) 0x7f8b9cba9470
root [1] .ls
TFile* output_idAntiId_Mc16a.root
TFile* output_idAntiId_Mc16a.root
KEY: TDirectoryFile plotEvent;1 plotEvent
KEY: TDirectoryFile pass_wgantiidcr_all_e_Nominal;1 pass_wgantiidcr_all_e_Nominal
KEY: TDirectoryFile pass_wgantiidcr_all_u_Nominal;1 pass_wgantiidcr_all_u_Nominal 
root [2] pass_wgantiidcr_all_e_Nominal->cd()
(bool) true
root [3] .ls
TDirectoryFile* pass_wgantiidcr_all_e_Nominal pass_wgantiidcr_all_e_Nominal
KEY: TDirectoryFile pass_wgantiidcr_all_e_Nominal;1 pass_wgantiidcr_all_e_Nominal
 KEY: TDirectoryFile plotEvent_Higgs;1 plotEvent_Higgs
KEY: TDirectoryFile plotEvent_Hyyd1;1 plotEvent_Hyyd1
KEY: TDirectoryFile plotEvent_Wy;1 plotEvent_Wy
KEY: TDirectoryFile plotEvent_zgamewk;1 plotEvent_zgamewk
root [4] plotEvent_Wy->cd()
(bool) true
root [5] .ls
TDirectoryFile* plotEvent_Wy plotEvent_Wy

KEY: TH1D w;1 w
KEY: TH1D wElEta;1 wElEta
KEY: TH1D wElPhi;1 wElPhi
KEY: TH1D wElPt;1 wElPt
KEY: TH1D wMuEta;1 wMuEta
KEY: TH1D wMuPhi;1 wMuPhi
KEY: TH1D wMuPt;1 wMuPt


root [7] wElEta->Draw()
Info in TCanvas::MakeDefCanvas: created default TCanvas with name c1
```

This gives me the desired plot but I am having trouble writing a macro that does all this and I do not have to keep typing this up over and over again I Tried the following,

```
 TFile *f= new TFile(“output_IdId_Mc16a.root”);
 f->ls()
 TH1F h1= (TH1F)f->Get("/pass_wgantiidcr_all_e_Nominal/plotEvent_Wy/wElEta");

 h1->Draw();
```

but it doesnt work any ideas ?

Comment: Please check the tags that you applied, in particular their description. Also, it would help if you extracted and provided a [mcve]. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: h1 should be a pointer to a TH1F, not a TH1F, and your cast also needs to be updated accordingly. This is what makes @Yury's answer work

Answer (score 1):

Try

```cpp
    TFile* f = TFile::Open("output_IdId_Mc16a.root");
    if (f)
    {
        TH1F* h1 = static_cast<TH1F*>(f->Get("pass_wgantiidcr_all_e_Nominal/plotEvent_Wy/wElEta"));
        if (!h1)
            printf("No such histogram found!\n");
    }
    else
        printf("No such file found!\n");
```